# How to make Vite copy static assets from package dependency into output folder?

Tags: vite, monorepo

### Tldr

I have a dependency of my Vite app that has JS files which import images. I want my Vite app to import those JS files properly, including copying the images to the final build.

Instead, when transforming, Vite is changing the image import paths to an absolute one: `/@fs/Users/Patrick/git/my-app/common/dist/image.png`

### Details

My Vite app has a dependency `@stuff/common` that lives in the same monorepo, and the dependency has some images (svgs, pngs, etc) that it outputs into its dist folder.

Files:

```
ui/
    ... my vite app
    package.json
common/
    dist/
        bundle1.mjs   <- This import image.svg
        bundle2.mjs   <- This imports another.png
        image.svg
        another.png
    ...code
    package.json
```

The bundles in `common/dist` import images directly as string paths, like this:

```js
import image from './image.svg';
```

However, when I load the app, you can see that Vite has transformed the imported image path into **an absolute path that lives in `@stuff/common`...!** This will only work on my local machine and nowhere else:

[image: problem img tag]

How can I prevent Vite from doing this, and instead make it copy the images from the dependency into the public folder of the final build?